# Facebook share counter reset after HTTPS

Tags: facebook, .htaccess, https

I  just moved my blog to https and, of course, all the facebook shares counters are now reset to 0.

I've spent several hours reading stuff online and I got the solution to point the og:url tag to the old urls (with http instead of https).

It worked for a day but now all the counters are back to 0.

The strange thing is that if I check the urls (both with https and http) with the open graph debugger it returns me 0 shares for both the urls!

I really don't know what to do! Is there a way to have back the counters of the http-version of the urls? Or, as an alternative, is there a way to sum the two counters?

p.s. I already activated the 301 redirect for the whole blog in my .htaccess file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook treats HTTP and HTTPS as two different URLs and therefor two different Open Graph objects, even if the rest of it is the same.

> p.s. I already activated the 301 redirect for the whole blog in my .htaccess file.

And that's your mistake ... You *need* to keep the old HTTP URLs available for the FB scraper to read the OG meta data from; if you redirect the scraper to the HTTPS version as well, then it concludes that the HTTPS versions was the actual correct URL for this piece of content - and therefor you have just *undone* what you tried to do by having og:url point to the old HTTP address.

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs#faq_1149655968420144 for more details.

The scraper can be recognized by the User-Agent request header it sends - see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/crawler

(How to exclude clients that send a certain user agent from redirection via .htaccess is something that should be easy enough to research.)

Comment: That's a great answer... thanks a lot!
My big doubt now is: what about SEO? I immediately activated the 301 redirect because all the guides out there put this as the first step in moving to https.

Comment: What about SEO? You exclude the FB scraper from the redirect, not any other user agents, whether they be  normal users or search engines.

Comment: Just trying to recap. If I got it right your solution is: 1) keep both urls active; 2) set the 301 redirect for everyone but the FB scraper; 3) set the og:url to the HTTP version. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, if you want the twitterable version of it, that's it ;)

Comment: LOL. Thanks a lot, man! I've been reading guides and tutorials in the last two days and they all miss the step 2!